# Percentage-Width Divs don't fit

Tags: html, css, layout

This is killing me. My problem is that two Divs of with percentage widths *do not* fit together. Last time I checked, 75% + 25% = 100%, but somehow, they always break layout, and the unruly text goes into the next available empty space.

As you will see in the simplified example below, I've tried using display: inline-block, float: left float: right, white-space:nowrap, and overflow: hidden.

```css
      #reddiv {
        width: 75%;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        /*white-space:nowrap;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
      }
      #bluediv {
        width: 25%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        /*float: right;*/
        /*white-space:nowrap;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    #reddiv {
      width: 75%;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      /*white-space:nowrap;*/
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
    #bluediv {
      width: 25%;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      /*float: right;*/
      /*white-space:nowrap;*/
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="reddiv"></div>
  <div id="bluediv"></div>

  <p>Unruly text</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `box-sizing:border-box` to your divs (or to all divs, or to *)

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
```

See success in below code snippet.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#reddiv {
        width: 75%;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        /*white-space:nowrap;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
      }
      #bluediv {
        width: 25%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        /*float: right;*/
        /*white-space:nowrap;*/
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    #reddiv {
      width: 75%;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      /*white-space:nowrap;*/
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
    #bluediv {
      width: 25%;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      /*float: right;*/
      /*white-space:nowrap;*/
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="reddiv"></div>
  <div id="bluediv"></div>

  <p>Unruly text</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Further Reading:

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Impeccable! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Those are correct, but you also have to realize when using display: inline-block, white space is accounted for. so 75% + 25% +a little whitespace = more than 100% see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u9z1euwn/

```
<div id="reddiv"></div><div id="bluediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gibberish's answer is correct. In terms of the float vs. inline-block, in this scenario you will want to use float. Inline-block has built in margins, and will not allow you to use the 75% + 25%.

The CSS should look like this.

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#reddiv {
        width: 75%;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;

      }
      #bluediv {
        width: 25%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        float: left;

      }
```